# Disable empty rectangle when long touching back button - NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, storyboard

Problem:
The navigation bar back button shows an empty rectangle when I deep/hold/long it.

Need:
How to disable this behavior but at the same time I want to keep the back button existence and functionality but without the long touch showing this rectangle.

[image]
[image]

Note: I'm using UIKit

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini thank you for answering and following up, I tried your suggestion it didnt work, or i tried it wrong, its worth mentioning that i dont use SwiftUI in my code. Thanks again

Comment: The first method does not specific to SwiftUI. What is the issue?

Comment: i dont know where to put this: UIViewController.classInit, i tried like this:  public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("He")
        UIViewController.classInit
    }

Comment: You haven't provide any code so I can't tell specifically. But you should put it anywhere soon. Like the AppDelegate did finish launch... or anywhere before the navigation get's initialized

Comment: i added UIViewController.classInit  in the didfinishloading, right before the return true in appdelegete, didnt work, i dont know what i am missing, what could i provide to help identifying the issue

Answer (score 0):

That is not a simple rectangle. That is actually a menu to show the navigation stack. It will have more buttons if you navigate deeper. This can't be get rid of with normal APIs but you can get around it wit some swizzling:

1. Implement this:

```
private func swizzle(
    targetClass: AnyClass,
    originalSelector: Selector,
    swizzledSelector: Selector
) {
    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, swizzledSelector)
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
}

extension UIViewController {
    static let classInit: Void = {
        let originalSelector = #selector(viewWillAppear(_:))
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(swizzledViewWillAppear(_:))
        swizzle(
            targetClass: UIViewController.self,
            originalSelector: originalSelector,
            swizzledSelector: swizzledSelector
        )
    }()

    @objc func swizzledViewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            let backButton = BackBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
        }
        swizzledViewWillAppear(animated)
    }
}

class BackBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
    override var menu: UIMenu? {
        get { super.menu }
        set { }
    }
}
```

2. Call `UIViewController.classInit` some where early (like the init of a view in SwiftUI or a view controller in UIKit):

###### UIKit demo - AppDelegate

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UIViewController.classInit
        return true
    }
}
```

###### SwiftUI demo

```
struct SomeView: View {
    init() {
        UIViewController.classInit
    }

    ,,,
}
```

The point is to put it anywhere soon before the navigation get's initialized!

[image: Demo]

---

###### Keep the menu with a workaround - SwiftUI

Instead of above method, you can set the correct navigation title name `onDisappear` to make it work as expected:

```
struct NavigationTesting: View {
    @State var title: LocalizedStringKey = " "

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("Next") {
                Text("View 2")
            }
            .navigationTitle(title)
            .onDisappear { title = "Page 1" }
            .onAppear { title = " " }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can populate the menu with the correct name and keeping the "back" title hidden as intended.

[image: Demo]

Comment: I have updated the answer based on the comments on the original question